# Using Async Await Function as a OnPress for Button in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, firebase-storage

I am quite new to `React Native` and in general with `JavaScript`. Especially with the `JSX` etc, I have just started to learn it. I have a button which when pressed should do the following:

```js
const uploadImage = async (uri: string) => {  
    const pathToFile = uri;
    try {
    const response = await reference.putFile(pathToFile);
    const data = response.state;
    console.log(data);
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
    const imageUrl = await reference.getDownloadURL();
    setImageUrl(imageUrl);
  }
```

But I get the error

> Types of parameters 'uri' and 'event' are incompatible.

I suppose it is because of the use of `await` keyword. But I am not sure how to write the above function in a way which won't hamper the await (important for `Firebase` work) yet when button pressed, it calls this function.

Maybe one solution is to split the function but it would still yield this error as await is still going to be used.

**Edit**
I am calling this function using this:

```js
<Button title="Upload Invoice" onPress={uploadImage(uri)} />
```

URI is the uri of the selected image using launchCamera or launchImageLibrary.

Comment: Please show how you are calling the function and what you're giving as an argument

Comment: hope the edit makes it clearer.

Comment: What is "event"?

Comment: Where is "event" mentioned? Sorry.

Comment: In the error message

Answer (score 3):

Try calling the function like this:

```js
<Button title="Upload Invoice" onPress={() => uploadImage(uri)} />
```

See [Responding to Events](https://react.dev/learn/responding-to-events) for details.

Comment: How is this different from the piece of code I wrote? I mean what is the difference between using the function directly versus calling it via () => method?

Comment: Because an `onPress` requires a function reference and `uploadImage` is a reference to a function, but by passing a parameter like this `uploadImage(url)` you called that function not passed to  `onPress`

so the solution is a `()=>` which is an arrow function which returns a `uploadImage(url)` so by this, we passed a function reference to the `onPress`instead of the function call

Comment: if this works for you, then please mark this answer as a solution

Comment: yes sir, this worked for me. thank you for the explanation as well.